# jquery, jcarousel full width with window area

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jcarousel

I've got a jcarousel object on my page that is set to 960px wide and centered, I've got overflow visible on the .jcarousel-clip with it set to 100% width so it's full window width.

I essentially want the run off from the carousel to always be visible, just like the new bbc beta slider, so I've set "wrap: circular"

If i set the start slide to 2 (not really what I want to do), the slider visually looks how I want it to, if I then navigate left(prev), the slider no longer goes to the edge of the window, when I then click prev again it briefly flashes the slide and moves it across. same when you go next a few times, you eventually come to a gap at the right of the screen.

So I guess I need to know if...

a) on jcourousel init, can you have the last slide staged to the left and still have start slide as 1 and...

b) can you stage the slides to the left and right on animation finish rather than on animation start?

have a look at the js fiddle example to see what I mean... http://jsfiddle.net/stikoo/3T97L/7/

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: p.s if anyone knows of a good alternative plugin that can do what I need, let me know. Thanks.